# need to develop CSPRNG. can i use ANSI X9.31 generator

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-generator

need to create secure PRNG. can i use ANSI X9.31 generator and modify its entropy rather using DT use something else >?

Comment: You want to use any from [NIST SP 800-90A rev.1 (PDF)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf).

Comment: You need to add some more detail.  Modify how and what's DT?

Comment: DT is Date Time vector. seed to the PRNG for ANSI X9.31 generator. Secure PRNG is one which has external entropy source in case its internal state is compromised still the entropy is high and cannot predict the next sequence. So my question is if DT is increasing linearly so ANSI PRNG is not secure. What if I use /urandom or some other function such as HMAC for giving as as seed ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any generator from [NIST SP 800-90A rev.1 (PDF)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf) as SEJPM indicated [in the initial comment above](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52615/need-to-develop-csprng-can-i-use-ansi-x9-31-generator#comment116329_52615).

---

Adding entropy is called *seeding* a random number generator. Seeding a PRNG with just date/time is sinful at best. Using a nano-second precision clock is only somewhat better; generally anybody can guess the value of the time so date / time itself is not random enough for *secure* random number generators.

Yes, you can seed using `/dev/urandom` which itself is a PRNG, seeded by the operating system. You could also use `/dev/random` (without the `u`) to retrieve a seed more directly from the *entropy pool* of the operating system. However, using `/dev/random` may cause performance issues and `/dev/random` may block as well. In general using `/dev/urandom` should be preferred.

If you use at least 128 bits of randomness from the `/dev/urandom` then your qualified PRNG should be at least as secure as using `/dev/urandom` directly. The security of `/dev/urandom` of course relies on the implementation, configuration and indeed the quality of the entropy it relies on. You may also seed the date / time *in addition* to the 128 bits of entropy, but date / time brings so little benefit that you might as well skip that part.